# Multiple owl:inverseOf with different domains or ranges

Tags: rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology, protege

`owl:inverseOf` is often used to define inverse relations between properties. An axiom of the form `P1 owl:inverseOf P2` asserts that for every pair (x,y) in the property extension of P1, there is a pair (y,x) in the property extension of P2, and vice versa for example `hasChild` and `hasParent`.

How can I define such inverse relationships between object properties with multiple domains and ranges, such as:

```
hasOwner owl:inverseOf hasDog
hasOwner owl:inverseOf hasCat

Classes: Person, Dog, Cat
ObjectProperties: hasOwner, hasDog, hasCat
    hasOwner:
        Domains: Dog or Cat
        Ranges: Person
    hasDog:
        Domains: Person
        Ranges: Dog
    hasCat:
        Domains: Person
        Ranges: Cat
```

If I known `Mammy hasDog Spike` and `Mammy hasCat Tom`, how can I model the ontology so that the reasoner can infer `Spike hasOwner Mammy` and `Tom hasOwner Mammy`?

Comment: Some the answers explained this a bit, but in short, inverse of goes *both ways*. That means that from hasCat you'd be able to get hasOwner, **and vice versa**.  So if you make both hasCat and hasDog inverses of hasOwner you can go from x hasCat y to y hasOwner x to x hasDog y, which is **not**,  I think, what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Forgetting about the incomprehensible restriction that anything that has an owner is either a cat or a dog, you can get closer to a reasonable model with (in Turtle syntax):

```
hasDog rdfs:subPropertyOf [ owl:inverseOf hasOwner ] .
hasCat rdfs:subPropertyOf [ owl:inverseOf hasOwner ] .
```

This has the non-advantage of not creating a new class name or a new property name.

PS: I *do* know things that have an owner and are neither cats nor dogs.

Comment: Nice catch. I thought about making `hasDog` and `hasCat` subproperties of `hasPet`, but your solution elegantly uses the inverse of `hasOwner` instead of defining it explicitely.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a flaw in your logic.

```
hasOwner owl:inverseOf hasDog
hasOwner owl:inverseOf hasCat
```

These two statements can only be true if `hasCat` and `hasDog` are identical. Think about it, if `P1` is the inverse of `P2` and the inverse of `P3`, then by transitivity `P2` must be the same as `P3`.

You should rather have a predicate `hasPet` as the inverse of `hasOwner`, create a class `Pet` and make `Dog` and `Cat` subclasses of it.

You could then make a rule to infer that from `P1 hasPet P2` and `P2 isA Cat` follows `P1 hasCat P2`.

Comment: Yes, I can create a new class and problem solved, but in this case I don't want to create any new class, or define new relation `hasOwner2 owl:inverseOf hasDog`, `hasOwner owl:inverseOf hasCat`.

Comment: Okay, but without a general `Pet` class, you can't have two different properties be the inverse of another property. It is logically not possible.

Comment: If I cannot make general classes, the only way is making new object properties, am I right?

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You could make `hasCatOwner` and `hasDogOwner`, each with their respective inverse property, yes.